# Simple pdo insert not working or displaying an error

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have this code that I want to use to insert a record to the table `t` in the database `tws` in mysql

```
<?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tws","root","suytf");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try{
    $id="67";
    $name="AJ";
    $lastname="uuu";
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t (name, lastname, id) VALUES (:name, :lastname, :id)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$name, ':lastname'=>$lastname, ':id'=>$id));
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e.getMessage();
}
```

It is not working and no error is displayed on my web browser screen when I execute this php script.. why?

I tried bindValue but it did not work either.

Comment: Any errors in the PHP log file?

Comment: What is `$e.getMessage();`? The syntax in PHP is `$e->getMessage();`

Comment: @Barmar it worked thanks to you.. please forgive me but i am sick and my boss wanted me to work om the project so i missedt the ->. REALLY thank you i'm so gracfull to you.

Comment: You should have gotten an error about the undefined function `getMessage()`. Make sure you have error reporting enabled.